# cygwin at-spi-bus-launcher and xwin-xdg-menu high cpu

Tags: cygwin, cygwin-x

Running cygwin/X I see at-spi-bus-launcher and xwin-xdg-menu are using most of the cpu. There are two instances of xwin-xdg-menu.

Between the three of them there isn't much left for anything else. How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Solution:**
Create a **~/.startxwinrc** file, and add one line:

```
exec sleep infinity
```

Make ~/.startxwinrc executable by running `chmod +x ~/.startxwinrc`.

**Reason I suspect this worked:**
[startxwin](https://x.cygwin.com/docs/man1/startxwin.1.html) searches for a ~/.startxwinrc file to execute when launching.  If startxwin does not find a ~/.startxwinrc file, startxwin will follow the default routine outlined in `/etc/X11/xinit/startxwinrc`.

The default routine launches /usr/bin/xwin-xdg-menu, somehow causing me to have two xwin-xdg-menu processes, one of them with very high cpu. Creating ~/.startxwinrc bypasses the default routine, disabling /usr/bin/xwin-xdg-menu from launching altogether.

[exec sleep infinity](https://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html#q-startxwinrc-exit) keeps the x server alive after launching.

*(This response is a copy from [my solution to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50399377))*

Answer (score 1):

```
rm -r ~/.dbus*
```

Then start XWin

If it's still stuck, open task manager and see if there are 2 XWin.exe processes
kill the one with lower memory usage

Comment: I think I have seen two XWin processes. I will try this next time.